# "Full Site" link lacks pointer cursor

Tags: bug, user-interface, design, mobile-web, markdown

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the Stack Overflow home page
2. Click "Mobile" at the bottom of the page.
3. Wait for the page to refresh and scroll to the bottom.
4. Hover over each of the links, noticing that hovering over "Full Site" leaves the default `cursor: text`.

I know that mobile devices with a touch screen would not show a cursor. However, this kind of thing drives me crazy. The `all.css` file used on the page already has `.footer-links a{`, so only the actual `cursor: pointer` must be added.